# Display images of Firebase Storage with a Firestore query to get image url in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fill a GridView.builder with images from my Firebase storage. I want to get the url from my Firestore database with a query. I couldn't find any good tutorial and tried to build the function by myself but it didn't work. In the FutureBuilder I print the snapshot variable that should have the data variable, but it has not.

```
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                height: deviceHeight * 0.35,
                width: deviceWith,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: getImages(),
                  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>snapshot) {
                    print(snapshot);
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                      return ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return ListTile(
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              title: Text(snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["name"]),
                              leading: Image.network(
                                  snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["url"],
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill),
                            );
                          });
                    } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
                      return Text("No data");
                    }
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  },
                ),
            ),
  Future getImages() {
    var data;
    page.where("userID",isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid).snapshots().listen((data){
      return data.docs;
    });
    return data;
  }
```

**I have only changed the Future function from the tutorial, not the FutureBuilder variables but I know that I have to change them.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the future method to the following:

```
 Future<QuerySnapshot> getImages() async {
    return await page.where("userID",isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid).get();
  }
```

`get()` returns a `Future<QuerySnapshot>`